# floor and ceil with number of decimals

Tags: python, numpy, floor, ceil

I need to floor a float number with an specific number of decimals.

So:

```
2.1235 with 2 decimals --> 2.12
2.1276 with 2 decimals --> 2.12  (round would give 2.13 which is not what I need)
```

The function `np.round` accepts a `decimals` parameter but it appears that the functions `ceil` and `floor` don't accept a number of decimals and always return  a number with zero decimals.

Of course I can multiply the number by `10^ndecimals`, then apply floor and finally divide by `10^ndecimals`

```
new_value = np.floor(old_value * 10**ndecimals) / 10**ndecimals
```

But I'm wondering if there's a built-in function that does this without having to do the operations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

Comment: This question asks for a number to be rounded. I don't want to round

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Neither Python built-in nor numpy's version of ceil/floor support precision.

One hint though is to reuse round instead of multiplication + division (should be much faster):

```
def my_ceil(a, precision=0):
    return np.round(a + 0.5 * 10**(-precision), precision)

def my_floor(a, precision=0):
    return np.round(a - 0.5 * 10**(-precision), precision)
```

**UPD:**
As pointed out by @aschipfl, for whole values `np.round` will round to the nearest even, which will lead to unexpected results, e.g. `my_ceil(11)` will return 12. Here is an updated solution, free of this problem:

```
def my_ceil(a, precision=0):
    return np.true_divide(np.ceil(a * 10**precision), 10**precision)

def my_floor(a, precision=0):
    return np.true_divide(np.floor(a * 10**precision), 10**precision)
```

Comment: I like this solution. Any idea why `ceil` and `floor` don't have a decimals parameter? It would be useful if the implementation allows it.

Comment: I don't know. Maybe it is because other languages didn't have it. I agree it would be helpful to have

Comment: Just a heads up, because of how python keeps floating point numbers manageable by displaying a rounded value instead the true machine value (See [https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html] this solution appears to work if you print the result.  But when I used pythons built in decimal module to display the exact value that’s stored in in the float I noticed that it is still not a perfect floor or ceil.  This is fine if you are calculating or printing the result, but could have an effect if you want to apply further operations after calculating the floor of the ceiling.

Comment: `$ Decimal(np.round(1.128345345 + 0.5 * 10**(-2), 2)) Decimal('1.12999999999999989341858963598497211933135986328125')`

Comment: Note that this output comes directly from `round`. Numpy explicitly mentions in the documentation its `round` is less precise than native Python version

Comment: @B.Ackerman The reason for that is 10 not being a power of 2 that most decimal fractions have no exact representation as floats. Try `decimal.Decimal(0.1)`. As long as you are using floats there is nothing that can be done about this.

Comment: Would this not return wrong results when `a` is an integer, because `np.round()` rounds to the nearest even integer?

Comment: @aschipfl you're right, and it also affects floats. I do not have an immediate solution that will work equally well for all types of input, but will add later when/if I find something

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the integer problem could be resolved by using the built-in `round` function, which rounds up when the argument is exactly halfway between two integers, but signs must then be dealt with specifically…

Answer (score 6):

This seems to work (needs no import and works using the // operator which should be faster than numpy, as it simply returns the floor of the division):

```
a = 2.338888
n_decimals = 2
a = ((a*10**n_decimals)//1)/(10**n_decimals)
```

Comment: Yes, this is almost the same as I'm doing. I prefer using `floor` since sometimes I'm doing `ceil` instead and I can have the code with the same syntax for readability

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki This runs in slightly less than half the time as compared to the numpy method that you mentioned in the question and is 13-14 times faster than the accepted answer (which is slowest of the 3 methods).
Creating a custom function with this method is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

If regular expressions are an option, you can give this a go:

```
import re

def truncate(n, d):
  return float(re.search('\d+\.\d{}'.format(d), str(float(n)))[0])

print(truncate(2.1235, 2))
print(truncate(2.1276, 2))
```

Output:

```
2.12
2.12
```

Another solution using `str.split`:

```
def truncate(n, d):
  s = str(float(n)).split('.')
  return float('{}.{}'.format(s[0], s[1][:d]))

print(truncate(2.1235, 2))
print(truncate(2.1276, 2))
```

Output:

```
2.12
2.12
```

Comment: This works, but I think this is even more complicated than just doing the multiplication and division that I'm currently doing

Comment: Passing an `int` to this could lead to surprises (if it's not always guaranteed you're going to get floats...)

Comment: @JonClements You're right, casting `n` to `float` solves this.

Answer (score -1):

For C++ devs or a general solution that worked for me:

```cpp
float a, b;

// a = 2.05
// b = 2

c = (ceil((a-b)*1000))/1000;
```