# Rounding calculated column to 1dp

Tags: python, pandas, rounding

I am conscious this is a popular query but I haven't found anything on here that quite matches what I need. I have a column in a table that is rounding 36.25 to 36.2 rather than 36.3. Having read about this extensively on here I appreciate the details, however this doesn't help me solve my problem. How can I create some code that will round my 'Outcome' column as I wish please? This code produces a version of the df I am using:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

raw_data = {'AreaCode' : ['101', '102', '103', '104'],
            'Numerator' : [300, 500, 600, 667],
            'Denominator' : [1000, 780, 1100, 1840]}
Data = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['AreaCode', 'Numerator', 'Denominator'])
```

And then i am trying to add an 'Outcome' column:

```
Data['Outcome'] = Data['Numerator'] / Data['Denominator'] * 100
```

Produces table below:

```
AreaCode|Numerator|Denominator|Outcome
101|300|1000|30.000000 
102|500|780|64.102564 
103|600|1100|54.545455
104|667|1840|36.25000
```

Which is fine except when I apply `Data = Data.round(1)` to this, it rounds 36.250000 to 36.2. I need this column to 1dp showing as 36.3 but how can I code this in Python. Examples on here of how to do this use strings of one-off, user-entered numbers, rather than an entire df.column. It won't let me pass my df.column into these. One example I tried which didn't work:

```
import math
def my_round(n, ndigits):
    part = n * 10 ** ndigits
    delta = part - int(part)
    # always round "away from 0"
    if delta >= 0.5 or -0.5 < delta <= 0:
        part = math.ceil(part)
    else:
        part = math.floor(part)
    return part / (10 ** ndigits
```

Comment: How about `round_up` function used here: https://www.knowledgehut.com/blog/programming/python-rounding-numbers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [floor and ceil with number of decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58065055/floor-and-ceil-with-number-of-decimals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a little tweak to your function and it seems to work now :)

```
def my_round(n, ndigits=1):
    try:
       part = n * 10 ** ndigits
       delta = part - int(part)
       # always round "away from 0"
       if delta >= 0.5 or -0.5 < delta <= 0:
           part = math.ceil(part)
       else:
           part = math.floor(part)
       val =  part/(10 ** ndigits)
    except ValueError:
       val = np.nan
    return val

Data['Outcome'] = (Data['Numerator'].divide(Data['Denominator'])*100).apply(my_round)
print(Data)
```

Output:

```
  AreaCode  Numerator  Denominator  Outcome
0      101        300         1000     30.0
1      102        500          780     64.1
2      103        600         1100     54.5
3      104        667         1840     36.3
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I had hoped it was the solution but when I execute on the data I've imported it is returning the error 'ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer', despite me having used .fillna(0) to turn all these to zero. Is there something else I can add to the code above to eradicate this?

Comment: Sure, the way I'd do it is using `try` and `except` check the edit and let me know if it works please!

Comment: This is superb thanks Celius, working perfectly as we need now. A massive help for us cheers

Comment: Hi Celius. Is there any modification I can make to your ceil/floor code used above in order to use it to round to nearest 5 whole numbers? i.e. I have figures such as 702.5 rounding to 700 rather than 705 when I'm trying to round to 5.

Answer (score 0):

After importing pandas to your notebook, you can add this line so that your float values will not exceed one decimal place:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.1f}'.format
```

Comment: Thank you for help with this. I need the actual calculation to round up though, not just display to 1dp. I am calculating NHS performance indicators and the 36.25 being shown as 36.2 won't be acceptable