# numpy round compare array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm currently working with the numpy float array.

My problem is that I'd like to compare them with, say, 3 decimal places.

But when I try to use round or around, it doesn't work.

If you know a way I'd be very grateful.

Here's the code I tried

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array(([0.32745, -1.043, -0.633], [0.418, -1.038, -1.166]), dtype=float)
y = np.array(([0.32788, -1.043, -0.633], [0.418, -1.038, -1.166]), dtype=float)

x = np.round(x, 3)
y = np.round(y, 3)

if (x == y).all():
    print("ok")
```

Comment: At 3 decimal points `0.32745` rounds down and `0.32788` rounds up, so they are not equal. Perhaps you were looking for floor instead of round? Take a look at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58065394/1011724

Comment: You wrote you would like to compare the values in the array with 5 decimal places, but you have rounded them to 3  decimal places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At 3 decimal points 0.32745 rounds down and 0.32788 rounds up, so they are not equal. An easier solution might be to use numpy's [`isclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) setting the absolute precision argument `atol`:

```py
import numpy as np

decimal_points = 3

x = np.array(([0.32745, -1.043, -0.633], [0.418, -1.038, -1.166]), dtype=float)
y = np.array(([0.32788, -1.043, -0.633], [0.418, -1.038, -1.166]), dtype=float)

if np.isclose(x, y, atol=1e-decimal_points).all():
    print("ok")
```

There is also [`allclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html#numpy.allclose) which would allow you to drop your call to `.all()`

This will compare if the absolute difference between the numbers is lower than your precision requirement, so in this case lower than `0.001`. This is subtly different from rounding (or flooring), but since you expected the data in your question to match, I think this is actually what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic idea is correct, but your data is wrong.

The first numbers in `x` and `y` round to `0.327` and `0.328`, which is why your equality statement (correctly) returns false. Try rounding them to 2 decimal places, and everything works as expected.

```
>>> np.round(x,3)
array([[ 0.327, -1.043, -0.633],
       [ 0.418, -1.038, -1.166]])
>>> np.round(y,3)
array([[ 0.328, -1.043, -0.633],
       [ 0.418, -1.038, -1.166]])
>>> np.round(x,2) == np.round(y,2)
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
>>> (np.round(x,2) == np.round(y,2)).all()
True
```