# Finding duplicates and creating sets in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Input:

| Part no | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 0.25 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 0.4 |
| A2 | 0.26 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.4 |
| A3 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.3 |
| A4 | 0.7 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.3 |
| A5 | 0.8 | 0.4 | 0.45 | 0.46 |

I have to create set for duplicates on the column A with the tolerance of +/-0.1

Expected output

| Part no | A | B | C | D | Set |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 0.25 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 0.4 | 1 |
| A2 | 0.26 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.4 | 1 |
| A3 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 1 |
| A4 | 0.7 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 2 |
| A5 | 0.8 | 0.4 | 0.45 | 0.46 | 2 |

Comment: I too have this question If any one know the solution add answer to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cumsum` to create groups:

```
# If your dataframe is not sorted by 'A' columns
df = df.sort_values('A')

df['Set'] = df['A'].sub(df['A'].shift()).abs().ge(0.1000000001).cumsum().add(1)
```

```
>>> df
  Part no     A    B     C     D  Set
0      A1  0.25  0.2  0.30  0.40    1
1      A2  0.26  0.3  0.30  0.40    1
2      A3  0.30  0.3  0.30  0.30    1
3      A4  0.70  0.3  0.30  0.30    2
4      A5  0.80  0.4  0.45  0.46    2
```

`0.1000000001` is due to float precision. You can also use [`np.isclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html).

With `np.close`:

```
>>> df['Set'] = np.cumsum(~np.isclose(df['A'], df['A'].shift(), atol=0.1))

  Part no     A    B     C     D  Set
0      A1  0.25  0.2  0.30  0.40    1
1      A2  0.26  0.3  0.30  0.40    1
2      A3  0.30  0.3  0.30  0.30    1
3      A4  0.70  0.3  0.30  0.30    2
4      A5  0.80  0.4  0.45  0.46    2
```

Comment: how to set tolerance in this between +/- 0.1. suggest me some idea

Comment: oh that was really nice it is working fine, Can I add multiple columns with different set of tolerance in this @Corralian

Comment: can we set tolerance between -0.1 to 0.1

Comment: I have already updated my answer. Use `abs()` to convert the difference to a positive number (not needed for `np.isclose`)

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work for you? The last example of 0.7 and 0.8 is a bit strange anyways. Why would you like them in the same group?

Reference to `my_ciel` answer since nor python nor numpy has the builtin functionality to do a cieling round on arbitrary float positions: [my_ciel answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58065394/7099374)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


# Some boilerplate to make your sample data reusable (I suggest u post your questions in such way
# that data can be easily coppied)
a = np.array([0.25,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.26,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.7,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.8,0.4,0.45,0.46,])
a = a.reshape(5,4)

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df.columns = ["A","B","C","D"]
df["PartNo"] = ["A1","A2","A3","A4","A5"]
df = df[["PartNo","A","B","C","D"]]


# This does a cieling round at the desired float position 
def my_ceil(a, precision=0):
    return np.true_divide(np.ceil(a * 10**precision), 10**precision)


# Tolerance can be set here:
# 1 = 0.1 , 2 = 0.01 , 3 = 0.001 etc.
df["set"] = my_ceil(df["A"],1)
df["set"] = df["set"].astype('category').cat.codes
df
```

Comment: Where can i change tolerance in this code

Comment: I edited the answer to show where to change tolerance