# Rounding up to two limits in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to round up to nearest 10 for `Max` and `Min`. However, for `Max`, the nearest 10 should be greater than `Max` and for `Min`, the nearest 10 should be less than `Min`. The current and the expected outputs are presented.

```
import numpy as np
Max = [99.91540553]
Min = [8.87895014]
Amax=round(Max[0],-1)
Amin=round(Min[0],-1)
```

The current output is

```
Amax=100
Amin=10.0
```

The expected output is

```
Amax=100
Amin=0.0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [floor and ceil with number of decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58065055/floor-and-ceil-with-number-of-decimals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you'd need the floor and ceil functions from the math module.

```
import math as m
Max = [99.91540553]
Min = [8.87895014]
Amax = 10*m.ceil(Max[0]/10)
Amin = 10*m.floor(Min[0]/10)
```

These also exist in numpy if you would like to perform this on every element in a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
Max = np.array([99.91540553, 95.7, 93.2])
Min = np.array([8.87895014, 15.7, 17.2])
Amax = 10*np.ceil(Max/10)
Amin = 10*np.floor(Min/10)
```

Comment: Thanks Murali, I forgot to divide by 10.

Answer (score 2):

You can use math.floor and math.ceil, these functions round only to units so we just divide by ten and then multiply by ten to round to tens.

```
import math
Max = [99.91540553]
Min = [8.87895014]
Amax= 10*math.ceil(Max[0]/10)
Amin= 10*math.floor(Min[0]/10)
print(Amax, Amin)
```

### Output

```
100 0
```